# Выбор строк из таблицы по условию

Tags: sql

Буду рад помощи добрых людей. Составил *SQL* запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT Row_Number() Over (Partition by Certificate_Id Order by DateAndTime) as Partit, Certificate_Id, Action, AH.DateAndTime 
from AuthorizationHistories AH INNER JOIN AuthorizationHistory_Certificate AHC ON AH.Id = AHC.Id 
WHERE Certificate_Id in (SELECT  AHC.Certificate_Id FROM AuthorizationHistories AH INNER JOIN AuthorizationHistory_Certificate AHC ON AH.Id = AHC.Id INNER JOIN Certificates C ON AHC.Certificate_Id = C.Id
WHERE Action = 'Overdue' and C.CertificateType_Id in (1, 2))
and Action in ('Overdue', 'Suspended', 'Job Completed')
```

запрос возвращает следующую таблицу:

[image: Результат]

Не получается из этой таблицы выбрать строки отмеченные желтым по условию. 
Условие: выбрать **`+1`** строку от той, которая содержит в столбце `Action` слово `Overdue`, затем объединить данные, чтоб результат содержал таблицу со строками `Overdue` и следующими за ними **`N+1`** строками, остальные, не соответствующие этому условию строки, удалить. Т.е. из предыдущей таблицы должно получиться следующее:

[image: Результат2]

Спасибо!

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3. И укажите ТОЧНО используемую СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: *Условие* - а если после записи с `Action = 'Overdue'` нет записей с тем же Certificate_Id? А если идёт две записи с `Action = 'Overdue'` подряд?

Comment: @Akina, MSS 2019. Если после записи с Action = 'Overdue' нет записей с тем же Certificate_Id = необходимо вывести только те, в которых есть запись с тем же Id, если идёт две записи с Action = 'Overdue' подряд, = все равно выводить +1 строку от первой записи т.е. также Overdue. Нужна конструкция для N+1 строки, с остальным вероятно справлюсь.

Comment: *MSS 2019* Это что? Специально же большими буквами написал - укажите ТОЧНО. *Если после записи с Action = 'Overdue' нет записей с тем же Certificate_Id = необходимо вывести только те, в которых есть запись с тем же Id* Ни хрена не понять. А поля `Id` в таблице вообще нет. *если идёт две записи с Action = 'Overdue' подряд, = все равно выводить +1 строку от первой записи т.е. также Overdue.* А записи с `Action = 'Overdue'` при этом выводить обе? В общем, [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina я вас услышал